# Problema para subir un archivo con PHP y Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, archivo

tengo el siguiente problema, si uso de manera nativa el subir un archivo al servidor me funciona sin problema, el detalle es que requiero enviar aparte del archivo, dos parametros que se tienen en el formulario que componen la ruta final del archivo.  Ya estuve leyendo muchos ejemplos de Ajax, y sigo sin encontrar el mecanismo adecuado para que me funcione.

El codigo que tengo actualmente este para lo que corresponde al Ajax:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("button#cargarArchivo<?=$i+1?>").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Acceso a la funcion cargar Archivo'); //Asi verifico que si entre a la funcion
            var nombreTipoUnidad=$("#nombreTipoUnidad<?=$i+1?>").val();
            alert('nombre de la Unidad: '+nombreTipoUnidad); // Me imprime el valor recibido
            var nombreProyectoUnidad=$("#nombreProyectoUnidad<?=$i+1?>").val();
            alert('nombre del proyecto: '+nombreProyectoUnidad); // Me imprime el valor recibid
            var formData = new FormData($('#archivo')[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: "procesarArchivo.php",
                type: "post",
                data: formData,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                    $("#modalCargaResguardoIndividual<?=$i+1?>").modal('hide');
                    swal("Se Cargo el Archivo Exitosamente!","Aceptar","success");
                    console.log("Alert Callback");
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("#modalCargaResguardoIndividual<?=$i+1?>").modal('hide');
                    swal("No se pudo Cargar el Archivo","Aceptar","error");
                    console.log("Alert Callback");
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

y este codigo es lo que corresponde al html

```html
<td>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="content" class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div id="respuesta" class="alert"></div>
                                    <form action="" method="post" id="formCargarArchivo<?=$i+1?>" name="formCargarArchivo" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                                        <div id="content" class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="archivo" id="archivo<?=$i+1?>" accept="application/pdf">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                                <button type="submit" id="cargarArchivo<?=$i+1?>"  class="btn btn-primary">Subir Archivo</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                                <progress id="barra_de_progreso" value="0" max="100"></progress>
                                            </div>

                                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="nombreTipoUnidad" id="nombreTipoUnidad<?=$i+1?>" value="<?=$nombreTipoUnidad?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="nombreProyectoUnidad"  id="nombreProyectoUnidad<?=$i+1?>" value="<?=$nombreProyectoUnidad?>">
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
```

y esto es lo que tengo en el archivo para php para procesar los datos

```html
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['archivo'])) {
    $archivo = $_FILES['archivo'];
    $archivo_nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $extension = pathinfo($archivo['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $ruta1= $_POST['nombreTipoUnidad'];
    $ruta2= $_POST['nombreProyectoUnidad'];
    $nombre = "{$_POST['nombreProyectoUnidad']}_$archivo_nombre";
    if (move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], "repositorio_resguardos_ieca/$ruta1/$ruta2/$nombre")) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Se que algo anda mal en alguna sección de los tres códigos, pero no logro ver o encontrar el error.

Se agradece cualquier aportación

Saludos

Comment: Puedes agregar valores con `formData.append('variable', 'valor');`

Comment: @Triby  Gracias déjame realizar una pruebas y te aviso!!!

Comment: @Triby tienes idea de este mensaje:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined , en esta linea:   paqueteDeDatos.append('archivo',$('#archivo')[0].files[0]);

Comment: Te sobra el primer `[0]`, porque `$("#archivo")` devuelve el campo, no la lista de archivos; debe ser: `paqueteDeDatos.append('archivo', $('#archivo').files[0]);`

Comment: Que crees @Triby que manda un error si le quito ese primer[0] y se queda pegado el modal en la pantalla, ya que lo volvi añadir, funciona sin problema, lo unico que ahora me manda un mensaje de error que no se pudo efectuar la carga y si lo guarda en donde se indica jajaja... En fin.

Comment: Intenta con `paqueteDeDatos.append('archivo', $('#archivo').prop('files')[0]);` y, si te marca error, especifica cuál es. ¿Tienes varios formularios? ¿O por qué agregas `i+1` en el ID?

Comment: @Triby Este codigo es parte de un datatable, para que me muestre correctamente los datos en un modal tengo que añadir el indice del listado en el orden que guarda en el datatable, y a su vez para que me carge los datos en el modal correctamente tambien tengo que añadir ese indice, solo de esta manera me ha funcionado, asi que carga el renglon 4, habre el modal 4, y carga los datos del renglon 4 dentro del modal 4.... que engorroso verdad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que estás creando una función en Javascript para cada botón y eso no es correcto, debes tener solo una.

Elimina ID's de formularios, campos y botones, no los necesitas realmente, basta con obtener el formulario y agregarlo directamente a un `FormData`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Click en cualquier botón tipo submit con clase btn-primary
    // De puede ser más específico, proporcionando ID de tabla
    $('button[type="submit"].btn-primary').click(e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Obtener formulario desde el botón que recibió el clic
        let form = e.target.closest('form');
        // Crear FormData directamente desde el formulario, no se requiere más
        let formData = new FormData(form);
        // Todos los campos se van a incluir
        console.log(...formData);
        $.ajax({
            url: "procesarArchivo.php",
            type: "post",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
                $("#modalCargaResguardoIndividual<?=$i+1?>").modal('hide');
                swal("Se Cargo el Archivo Exitosamente!","Aceptar","success");
                console.log("Alert Callback");
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#modalCargaResguardoIndividual<?=$i+1?>").modal('hide');
                swal("No se pudo Cargar el Archivo","Aceptar","error");
                console.log("Alert Callback");
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="content" class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div id="respuesta" class="alert"></div>
                                    <form action="" method="post" name="formCargarArchivo" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                                        <div id="content" class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="archivo" accept="application/pdf">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subir Archivo</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                                <progress id="barra_de_progreso" value="0" max="100"></progress>
                                            </div>

                                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="nombreTipoUnidad" value="<?=$nombreTipoUnidad?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="nombreProyectoUnidad" value="<?=$nombreProyectoUnidad?>">
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="content" class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div id="respuesta" class="alert"></div>
                                    <form action="" method="post" name="formCargarArchivo" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                                        <div id="content" class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="archivo" accept="application/pdf">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subir Archivo</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                                <progress id="barra_de_progreso" value="0" max="100"></progress>
                                            </div>

                                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="nombreTipoUnidad" value="Segundo tipo de unidad">
                                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="nombreProyectoUnidad" value="Segundo nombre de unidad">
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Lo único que falta por resolver es el problema de los modales, deberías tener solo uno y llenarlo con los datos necesarios, pero eso es tema de otra pregunta.

Comment: Si así es @Triby, al tener el problema del modal, que solo me carga el ultimo o el primer registro de la consulta, y por eso lo de los indices, tuve que hacerlo así, para que pudieran cada botón tener su propia función. Quizás el problema sea el como estoy manejando las consultas para rellenar los modales.

Comment: @Cesarin, crea una nueva pregunta para solucionar el problema de modales, no olvides incluir toda la información necesaria: cómo los creas, cómo los activas y especificar si necesitas obtener datos que no incluyes en _dataTables_.

Comment: Ok @Triby, así como me indicaste realice una prueba y funciona perfectamente.  Deja colocar el tema del modal.

Comment: listo @Triby ya esta lo del modal publicado.  Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si no hay problema, puedes enviar los parámetros a través de la URL y no por `POST`

```javascript
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("button#cargarArchivo<?=$i+1?>").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Acceso a la funcion cargar Archivo'); //Asi verifico que si entre a la funcion
            var nombreTipoUnidad=$("#nombreTipoUnidad<?=$i+1?>").val();
            alert('nombre de la Unidad: '+nombreTipoUnidad); // Me imprime el valor recibido
            var nombreProyectoUnidad=$("#nombreProyectoUnidad<?=$i+1?>").val();
            alert('nombre del proyecto: '+nombreProyectoUnidad); // Me imprime el valor recibid
            var formData = new FormData($('#archivo')[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: "procesarArchivo.php?nombreTipoUnidad="+$("#nombreTipoUnidad").val()+"&nombreProyectoUnidad="+$("#nombreProyectoUnidad").val(),
                type: "post",
                data: formData,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                    $("#modalCargaResguardoIndividual<?=$i+1?>").modal('hide');
                    swal("Se Cargo el Archivo Exitosamente!","Aceptar","success");
                    console.log("Alert Callback");
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("#modalCargaResguardoIndividual<?=$i+1?>").modal('hide');
                    swal("No se pudo Cargar el Archivo","Aceptar","error");
                    console.log("Alert Callback");
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```php
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['archivo'])) {
    $archivo = $_FILES['archivo'];
    $archivo_nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $extension = pathinfo($archivo['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $ruta1= $_GET['nombreTipoUnidad'];
    $ruta2= $_GET['nombreProyectoUnidad'];
    $nombre = "{$_GET['nombreProyectoUnidad']}_$archivo_nombre";
    if (move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], "repositorio_resguardos_ieca/$ruta1/$ruta2/$nombre")) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Ya estás enviando un `FormData` por POST

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, no quiero abusar del uso del get, previa pantalla el acceso a donde quiero realizar esta acción, precisamente hago uso de get, para traer un valor y así poder obtener mediante una consulta una serie de datos incluidos los que quiero pasar ahora por Ajax. Pero si no me queda otra opciones pues terminare haciéndolo como me comentas .  Gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

En base a la aportación de Triby se hizo el siguiente cambio en el script:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("button#cargarArchivo<?=$i+1?>").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var paqueteDeDatos = new FormData();
            paqueteDeDatos.append('archivo',$('#archivo<?=$i+1?>')[0].files[0]);
            paqueteDeDatos.append('nombreTipoUnidad',$("#nombreTipoUnidad<?=$i+1?>").val());
            paqueteDeDatos.append('nombreProyectoUnidad',$("#nombreProyectoUnidad<?=$i+1?>").val());
            $.ajax({
                url: "subirArchivo.php",
                type: "post",
                data: paqueteDeDatos,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(msg){
                    //alert(msg);
                    $("#modalCargaResguardoIndividual<?=$i+1?>").modal('hide');
                    swal("Se Cargo el Archivo Exitosamente!","Aceptar","success");
                    console.log("Alert Callback");
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("#modalCargaResguardoIndividual<?=$i+1?>").modal('hide');
                    swal("No se pudo Cargar el Archivo","Aceptar","error");
                    console.log("Alert Callback");
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Y en efecto ya procesa el archivo y envía los datos requeridos para indicar la ubicación del archivo en cuestión.  Ahora lo extraño es que en lugar de indicarme que la carga ha sido exitosa, me envía la ventana de error y en el repositorio aparece el archivo, modificado y en la ruta especificada.

Gracias Triby!! eres un crack!!

Comment: Todavía no queda al 100%, estoy preparando una respuesta