# Cambiar un formulario y enviarlo por AJAX PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un modal para subir un archivo PDF a PHP
Pero no me gusta la idea de abrir una pestaña nueva para notificar si fue correcto o no

Existe algún modo de cambiar el envio de este formulario a AJAX o JQuery con tal de obtener la respuesta en la misma pagina web ???

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span><!-- boton de cierre -->
    <form action="subirPDF.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Subir un Archivo:
        <input type="file" name="file" required><br><br>
        Observacion: <input type="text" name="observacion"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-success" value="Subir Archivo">
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/420571/54039), es con jQuery, pero puede hacerse casi igual con Javascript puro.

Comment: No se si te refieres a la misma página web desde donde has lanzado el modal (ante lo cual deberiamos ver su código para darte una respuesta certera y decirnos donde quieres el mensaje de vuelta) o bien desde el propio modal. En ambos casos ¿que necesitas ver?  ¿solo un mensaje de que ha subido bien o el nombre de archivo, etc?  (el mecanismo seria el mismo, es solo para responderte mejor)

Comment: donde esta el formulario y si, si esta bien o mal.

Comment: Y es exactamente eso, un formulario abierto en un modal que obtenga la respuesta por ajax o jquery... es lo unico que se me ocurre a lo que existe ahora que abre otra pestaña

Comment: No se porque ahora te abre otra pestaña, deberia abrirte el resultado de subirPDF.php sustituyendo la actual pestaña con su contenido, pues no tienes puesto un `target="_blank"` en el <form>... pero ese es otro tema... voy a ver si puedo ayudarte, aunque Triby ya te ha dado un buen enlace para mirar

Comment: si, el form manda a subirPDF.php, entonces cuando abre queda una pag nueva en blanco, que no es donde esta el modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en el código con jQuery de @triby, esto seria lo que seguramente te podria funcionar bien en tu caso concreto:

Para empezar modificamos el modal para que nos quede así:

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span><!-- boton de cierre -->
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Subir un Archivo:
        <input type="file" name="file" required><br><br>
        Observacion: <input type="text" name="observacion"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><br>
        <input type="submit" id="subirPDF" name="submit" class="btn-success" value="Subir Archivo">
    </form>
    <div id="respuestaSubida"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cambios realizados:

1. Le he quitado el `subirPDF.php` en el **action** del elemento `<form>`, lo cual no era necesario, pero para dejarlo más limpio. No era necesario porque no vamos a permitir que realice el `action`, ponga lo que ponga, pues vamos a capturar el evento `submit` del formulario y vamos a impedir que lo haga de la forma habitual. Lo haremos con ajax y jQuery.
2. He creado un div con un id denominado **respuestaSubida** donde vamos a colocar el mensaje de conformidad o de fallo que nos debe mandar el script en PHP `subirPHP.php` después de su ejecución
3. Le he agregado un id al botón `submit` denominado `subirPDF` para poder acceder a el con más facilidad (como no se si tienes más botones `submit` debajo del modal he preferido hacerlo así por si acaso).

Ahora vamos con la parte del ajax que debes agregar en tu modal o documento (adaptado desde [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/420571/263200)):

```javascript
$('#subirPDF').click(e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Obtener formulario desde el botón que recibió el clic
        let form = e.target.closest('form');
        // Crear FormData directamente desde el formulario, no se requiere más
        let formData = new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
            url: "subirPDF.php",
            type: "post",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#respuestaSubida").innerHTML = msg;
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#respuestaSubida").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">¡Error al acceder al archivo PHP! ¡Contactar con el administrador!</div>';
            }
        });
    });
```

Y por último, tienes que modificar tu archivo **subirPDF.php** para que cuando termine de gestionar la petición, mediante un condicional, devuelva, mediante un `echo` el texto que desees mostrar en el div `resultadoSubida`.

Por ejemplo así:

```php
if (condicion) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">El archivo ha subido satisfactoriamente</div>';
    die(); //esto lo pongo por si acaso, no sea que después haya más código, pero no haria falta segun como 
} else {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">¡Error! ¡El archivo no ha subido!</div>';
    die(); //esto lo pongo por si acaso, no sea que después haya más código, pero no haria falta segun como
}
```

Prueba a ver si te funciona y ya nos dirás.